# Trying to learn Spring Development but having a lot of problems

Tags: java, spring

I have previously posted a question based on spring. It had to do with what IDE to use. I have since downloaded STS.

I have been trying to learn spring from using this IDE and have tried to use books and tutorials I found online.

So far the book I am reading is SPRING ROO COOKBOOK. But it is not showing me how to start developing in Spring.

I am looking for something to try show from the VERY first step, as in from when I install STS, then start up a spring project and make my first web application which will run successfully.

I am sorry if what I am saying is vague and not clear but I am very very confused and just need a clear tutorial which can show me how to start a spring project in STS and take me step by step until it is successfully deployed.

If anyone can send me a direct link to something like this I would really appreciate it.

Again my apologies if it appears vague what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of Eclipse not the full STS because Eclipse does not hold your hand (and I already know eclipse without the STS extensions).

Give this a try:

1. Get the Spring Framework 3.0.6 with docs.
2. Start reading the reference (it's in the docs directory when you unpack).  In chapter 3 they start with the basics.
3. Create a java project with a main().
4. create a basic spring-config.xml file, put it in your project at the top of your src tree.  basic == 1 simple bean to start, add as you read through the chapter.
5. Begin testing with getBean() and System.out.println().
6. Add more to this project as you read through the reference.

Answer (score 0):

STS is one specific tool; you don't need it to work with Spring.  While it can be helpful, you should understand what is going on without it.

All the documentation you need is on the Spring website.  In addition, I found a sample application in those pages found [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/?__utma=1.871543953.1301667799.1306065597.1307026672.4&__utmb=1.1.10.1318512461&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1307026672.4.4.utmcsr=googleutmccn=organicutmcmd=organicutmctr=spring%20security%203%20is_authenticated_anonymously&__utmv=-&__utmk=171626144).

It's not very difficult to get up an running.  You need to download the jar(s), put them on your classpath, create your configurations, which reference the code you write (your components/beans), and do some general config, and you are set.  Look over the link I posted, it walks you thru the basic configurations and code.

If you run into any trouble, post a specific question on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all I have to say, I love STS (I must write it because of the other answers :-) )*

I know two good sources of Spring Understanding next to the [Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html):

- Book: [Spring In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182358)
- If you have a bit understanding of Spring, then you can also have a look at the Tutorials contained in STS!! itself: `Dashbord/Tutorials/`  *(@everybody else that never have seen this: feature, have a look at it, it is a great way to use Mylyn for tutorials!)*

But believe me learning Spring in all details takes several years. So the important thing is to understand the base concepts, and learn to read the spring source code.